# I have a keypress event on a textbox and appending a div , after appedning the form post automatically, what may be the reason?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

key press event of textbox, while pressing enter it does the desire task but after that it posts the form in which the text box called ItemIdentifier is placed.

```
$('#ItemIdentifier').on('keypress', function ()
{

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var duplicateChk = false;
        var counter = $('.indivisual-row.row').length;
        var itemId = $('#ItemIdentifier').val();
        var inputs = $('.indivisual-row.row').find('input');
        $.each(inputs, function (key, value) {
            var inputItemId = $(value).val();
            if (inputItemId == itemId) {
                alert('DuplicateEntry!!!!! ');
                ShowMessage("warning", "warning", 'Duplicate Entry!!!');
                duplicateChk = true;
                $('#ItemIdentifier').val('');
            }
        });
        if (!duplicateChk) {
            counter++;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Dispatch/CreateItemForAgentHandover"',
                data: { itemId: itemId, counter: counter },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $('#items-table-div').append(result);
                        $('#ItemIdentifier').val('');
                    }

                },
                error: function () {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#ItemIdentifier').on('keypress', function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
```

try the above and see it this works

more detailed documentation https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/